# Sniffing multiple ports of USB Hub simultaneously

Tags: ubuntu, usb, sniffing

I want to send data to an upstream port of a USB hub and read it through all downstream ports of the hub, each connected to a different device i.e broadcasting USB data. Basically to observe & ensure if data coming through all downstream ports of hub are same or not.
Are there any ways or tools to do this?
I am trying this on USB 2.0 hub and Ubuntu 18.04LTS system.

Comment: Data is sent to active devices, not hubs or specific ports. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Why do you need this? Hubs are designed to broadcast HS traffic, and are thoroughly verified by IC makers. Are you designing your own hub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To verify that all data are broadcast to all downstream ports of a USB 2.0 hub you will need the corresponding number of USB logic analyzers [(like this one)](https://teledynelecroy.com/protocolanalyzer/usb/mercury-t2) that are synchronized with a special (and hard to find) cable. You will need one analyzer on upstream side, and analyzers on each downstream port, between the hub and each of your devices.

Unfortunately, as far as I know, only two analyzers can be synchronized. So testing several downstream ports at once will be a challenge.